# How to display product.variation_price without currency in Drupal Commerce?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I need to display product price in the template `commerce-product.html.twig`

The variable `{{ product.variation_price }}` is rendered as currency and number e.g. `USD700`

And I can't understand how to display only number without currency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've just found the answer by myself.

If a product has only one variation, we can get its price as number in Twig like:

```
{% set price_number = product.variation_price['#items'].0.number %}
```

Now, according to [Displaying prices](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/pricing/displaying-prices) we can print it without fraction part like:

```
{{ price_number|number_format(0) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve this:

1. Use the `Commerce Currency Settings module`.
2. Implement `hook_commerce_currency_info_alter()` in your custom module.

Since the task is very simple and will most likely never need to be updated after initial setup, there is no need to install another module. This means less components to think about and update in the long run, and less pages in the admin.

By implementing this in your custom module you will also get complete freedom to change the format in which the values are displayed. You can replace the dollar sign with `USD`, move it `before / after` the value or add `custom labels`.

Here's the code you need to use:

```
 /**

 * Implements hook_commerce_currency_info_alter().

 */

function YOUR_MODULE_commerce_currency_info_alter(&$currencies) {

  // Get the abbreviation of the default currency. This will return "USD" for

  // US Dollars, "EUR" for Euros, etc.

  // If your site is using multiple currencies, you can skip this and just use

  // the abbreviation of the currency you want to change the format for.

  $default_currency = commerce_default_currency();

  $currencies[$default_currency]['format_callback'] = 'YOUR_MODULE_commerce_currency_format';

}

 

/**

 * Commerce currency format callback.

 */

function YOUR_MODULE_commerce_currency_format($amount, $currency, $currency_code, $object = NULL, $convert = TRUE) {

  // Format the price as a number.

  $price = number_format($amount, 2, $currency['decimal_separator'], $currency['thousands_separator']);

 

  // Establish the replacement values to format this price for its currency.

  $replacements = array(

    '@code_before' => $currency['code_placement'] == 'before' ? '' : '', //Here you can set empty or put $currency['code']

    '@symbol_before' => $currency['symbol_placement'] == 'before' ? '' : '', // set empty or $currency['symbol']

    '@price' => $price,

    '@symbol_after' => $currency['symbol_placement'] == 'after' ? '' : '', // set empty or $currency['symbol']

    '@code_after' => $currency['code_placement'] == 'after' ? '' : '', //set empty or $currency['code']

    '@negative' => $amount < 0 ? '-' : '',

    '@symbol_spacer' => $currency['symbol_spacer'],

    '@code_spacer' => $currency['code_spacer'],

  );     

  return trim(t('@code_before@code_spacer@negative@symbol_before@price@symbol_spacer@symbol_after@code_spacer@code_after', $replacements));

}
```

> NOTE: if you place the `hook_commerce_currency_info_alter()`
> implementation in `YOUR_MODULE.commerce.inc` file, the callback will
> still need to be placed in the `.module` file, because the `.commerce.inc`
> file will not be automatically loaded everywhere.

That's it - all prices will be displayed without currency code.

Comment: Thanks! But maybe there is a way how to get number only from `{{ product.variation_price }}` ? I see it's an object or an array

Comment: @stckvrw I do not see right now the way how you can do this. `variation_price` get pre-rendered value, so the only way to edit this is to catch it before it is rendered or if exist some `TWIG` functions to parse vars and extract the substrings.

Comment: Serghei Leonenco, Please see my own answer I've just found